# Printing JasperReports using velocity template

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, awt, velocity

I am using velocity script engine , i have a xml template file which has a format of how the report should be printed . I am taking the inputs from a JTextarea and printing the pdf.

The template file has :

```
      <line>
        <text align="left" length="15">Message:</text>
        <text>${report.printMessage()}</text>
      </line>
```

Now if the text box has multiple lines then it is printing in a single line .I want it be printed in different lines if the textarea has a newline ..

Please help ..
Thankx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay ...so here is the answer ..

user for loop ..

```
     <line>
        <text align="left" length="25">Message:</text>
     </line>
      #foreach ($messageline in $report.printMessage())
        <line>
          <text>${messageline}</text>
        </line>
      #end
```

here printMessage() is returning java.util.List :

```
public List<String> printMessage() {
    String temp = message;
    String[] r = {};
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
        r = temp.split("\n");
    }
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(r));
    return list;
}
```